# SharePoint 2010 - Automatically create a new content database when a size is reached

Tags: powershell, content-database

I've been asked a question today regarding the automatic creation of a new content database when the current one reaches a certain size limit.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Possibly with a Powershell script

Comment: Jon, I just want to be clear, you are not under the impression that a single site collection can use multiple content DBs, are you?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should look into site quota templates. In SharePoint site collection storage limits can be managed using site quota templates. The owner of the site collection gets an alert when a certain configurable limit is used. Moreover, a site collection cannot be split into multiple content database. You can however put each site collection in ts own database.

Answer (score 1):

Jon,

You can definitely start planning site collection quota templates to place limits on site collection size **+** Maximum Number of Site Collections (*Max Site Limit*) is the absolute limit for the number of site collections in the content database. SharePoint will not add any site collections beyond this number.

Combining above mentioned parameters will ensure to keep database size in check, while SharePoint will ensure logical and even distribution of newly created site collections across the content databases.

See more at: http://magenic.com/Blog/SiteCollectionManagementinSharePoint

Comment: Note that it is not an "even" distribution with regards to size - only the number of site Collections. So you have to watch out there!